# mypy indexing pd.DataFrame with an Enum raises no overload variant error

Tags: python, pandas, mypy

##### The issue

Mypy gives no overload variant of `__getitem__` of "DataFrame" matches argument type "MyEnum" error. In this case the argument type is an Enum but the issue would occur for any other custom type. Here is the signature of `__get_item__` below.

```
def __getitem__(self, Union[str, bytes, date, datetime, timedelta, bool, int, float, complex, Timestamp, Timedelta], /) -> Series[Any]
```

##### To reproduce

Here is a script (namely *mypy_enum.py*) creating a pandas dataframe with enums as columns.

```py
from enum import Enum
import pandas as pd

class MyEnum(Enum):
    TAYYAR = "tayyar"
    HAYDAR = "haydar"

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[12.2, 10], [8.8, 15], [22.1, 14]], columns=[MyEnum.TAYYAR, MyEnum.HAYDAR])
print(df[MyEnum.TAYYAR])
```

Here's the output when you call it. It works as expected, all is well.

```bash
> python mypy_enum.py
0    12.2
1     8.8
2    22.1
Name: MyEnum.TAYYAR, dtype: float64
```

When you call it with `mypy` however;

```bash
> mypy mypy_enum.py  
mypy_enum.py:12: error: No overload variant of "__getitem__" of "DataFrame" matches argument type "MyEnum"  [call-overload]
mypy_enum.py:12: note: Possible overload variants:
mypy_enum.py:12: note:     def __getitem__(self, Union[str, bytes, date, datetime, timedelta, bool, int, float, complex, Timestamp, Timedelta], /) -> Series[Any]
mypy_enum.py:12: note:     def __getitem__(self, slice, /) -> DataFrame
mypy_enum.py:12: note:     def [ScalarT] __getitem__(self, Union[Tuple[Any, ...], Series[bool], DataFrame, List[str], List[ScalarT], Index, ndarray[Any, dtype[str_]], ndarray[Any, dtype[bool_]], Sequence[Tuple[Union[str, bytes, date, datetime, timedelta, bool, int, float, complex, Timestamp, Timedelta], ...]]], /) -> DataFrame
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Shouldn't `__getitem__` be supporting the column type itself? How can this be addressed?

Comment: Try `class MyEnum(str, Enum)` or `df[MyEnum.TAYYAR.value]`: currently `mypy` is correct, `MyEnum` instances are **not** strings.

Comment: mypy is correct, yes. Pandas looks inconsistent. It allows other types to be used in index but its type signature says otherwise.

Comment: Please consider opening an issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/) to get this fixed (or get a maintainers' feedback explaining what's wrong now, if it is not a bug indeed). I suppose that they did not take Enum's into account, and the type for `__getitem__` should be simply `object`. This looks like they tried to avoid "overload signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types", but made things worse than with plain `object` (just reorder signatures and put `# type: ignore`, because no one will cast a `slice` to something else, even accidentally or conditionally).

Comment: Thanks, I did. It is here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/592#issuecomment-1485920524

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was due to a pandas bug fixed in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/pull/596

Comment: please no, it's certainly not a closure reason. The question is great, reveals a bug and finally even leads to its resolution - the only right thing to do here would be to post a self-answer with pull request attribution and explanation.

Comment: Alright, I posted a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to this [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/592) in `pandas-stubs`. It is now fixed in [PR/596](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/pull/596).

Before the fix, the type signature of the first overload of `__getitem__` was this:

```py
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, idx: Scalar | tuple[Hashable, ...]) -> Series: ...
```

The solution was to add `Hashable` type to that overload of `__getitem__`.

Here I am listing all 3 overloads of `__getitem__` after the fix.

```py
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, idx: Scalar | Hashable) -> Series: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, rows: slice) -> DataFrame: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(
        self,
        idx: Series[_bool]
        | DataFrame
        | Index
        | np_ndarray_str
        | np_ndarray_bool
        | list[_ScalarOrTupleT],
    ) -> DataFrame: ...
```

The example reported in the question meets the first overload now, therefore the type checkers are happy.